# Ansible async task with poll=0 living beyond timeout

Tags: asynchronous, ansible

For the context : ansible 2.7.9

I'm experimenting with Ansible asynchronous actions, and working with this playbook :

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

  - name: This is "long task", sleeping for {{ secondsTaskLong }} seconds
    shell: "[ -f testFile ] && rm testFile; sleep {{ secondsTaskLong }}; touch testFile"
    async: "{{ timeoutSeconds }} "
    poll: 0

  - stat:
      path: testFile
    register: checkTestFile

  - name: Check the test file exists
    assert:
      that: checkTestFile.stat.exists
...
```

**test 1 :**

```
ansible-playbook async.yml --extra-var "secondsTaskLong=2 timeoutSeconds=3"
```

The assertion fails, but if I check the directory contents, `ls` reveals the test file `./testFile` is here.

**test 2 :**

Testing with a 5s duration :

```
ansible-playbook async.yml --extra-var "secondsTaskLong=5 timeoutSeconds=3"; watch -n 1 -d "ls -l testFile"
```

The final `watch` part reveals that the test file is created a few seconds AFTER the end of the playbook execution.

**test 3 :**

Now with a 9s duration (i.e. way beyond the timeout) :

```
ansible-playbook async.yml --extra-var "secondsTaskLong=9 timeoutSeconds=3"; watch -n 1 -d "ls -l testFile"
```

The test file is still created.

**test 4 :**

Now trying with 10 seconds :

```
ansible-playbook async.yml --extra-var "secondsTaskLong=10 timeoutSeconds=3"; watch -n 1 -d "ls -l testFile"
```

The test file is NOT created.

What is going on exactly ? What allows this "long task" live for 9 seconds, beyond the timeout ? What kills it at 10 seconds ?

**EDIT:**

I can add an explicit connection timeout > 10s and still observe the same behavior :

```
ansible-playbook async.yml -T 20 --extra-var "secondsTaskLong=9 timeoutSeconds=3"; watch -n 1 -d "ls -l testFile"

ansible-playbook async.yml -T 20 --extra-var "secondsTaskLong=10 timeoutSeconds=3"; watch -n 1 -d "ls -l testFile"
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is going on exactly ? What allows this "long task" live for 9
>   seconds, beyond the timeout ? What kills it at 10 seconds ?

When `poll > 0`, ansible uses `async` value as timeout, otherwise, connection timeout (default is 10 seconds) is used. Refer the details on connection timeout [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-t) and `poll` value [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#avoid-connection-timeouts-poll-0).

For example, if you change the task like below and use `timeoutSeconds=3 and secondsTaskLong=4` then you will get timeout error after 3 seconds and assert will fail. However, for `timeoutSeconds=3 and secondsTaskLong=2`,  assert will be successful.

```
  - name: This is "long task", sleeping for {{ secondsTaskLong }} seconds
    shell: "[ -f testFile ] && rm testFile; sleep {{ secondsTaskLong }}; touch testFile"
    async: "{{ timeoutSeconds }} "
    poll: 1
```

Comment: Indeed, the examples with ```poll=1``` work as expected. But my question is specifically for tasks with ```poll=0```, i.e. when tasks run concurrently.

Comment: Got little bit of time over the weekend to test your given scenarios. test 1 ~ 4 can be explained by default connection timeout setting. However, same as you, I am also not able to change the timeout with `-T 20` using ansible 2.9.7.